# forEach inside provider service AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

`Error: this.filters.forEach is not a function`

```
.provider('searchFilter', function() {
  this.filters = {
    location : {
      default: 'Boston, MA',
      value: ''
    },
    radius : {
      default: '1',
      value: ''
    }
  }
  this.$get = function() {
      var filters = this.returnFilters();
      return {
          returnFilters: function() {
            return filters;
          }
      }
  };
  this.setLocation = function(location) {
      this.filters.location.default = location;
  };
  this.setRadius = function(radius) {
      this.filters.radius.default = radius;
  };
  this.returnFilters = function() {
    this.filters.forEach(function (filter) {
      filter.value = (filter.value=='')?filter.default:filter.value;
    });
    return this.filters;
  };
});
```

Why cant I use `forEach` inside a `.provider` service?

Comment: Looks like you have a small syntax error inside of your definition of filters. Note the trailing `,` after the last property.

Comment: @TravisJ Good catch but wasn't it unfortunately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`filters` is an object, it has no "forEach" method. You can however use `for(.. in ..)` or `Object.keys(..).forEach` (or even `angular.each` I think)

Comment: I use `forEach` on my JSON resource call responses, which are objects. What is the difference?

Comment: They're Arrays, not objects. `[].forEach` exists, `({}).forEach` does not

Comment: Resource calls seem to be type object in console log? `Object {a:'b',c:'d'}` Yet I run `forEach` on that data coming back somehow.

Comment: uuh.. Yeah ? Type `console.log({}.forEach)`, you'll get undefined. Type `console.log([].forEach)`, you'll get the function.